# Why doesn't my sorting method get called?

Tags: html, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3

This is my code:

```
<table border="1" id="champs">
<tbody id="item-list-body">
<tr class="champ" id="view-item-<%= champ.id %>">
<td class="drag_handle">[Déplacer]</td>
</tbody>
</table>
<%= sortable_element('item-list-body',:url => sort_update_path, :tag =>:tr, :handle => :drag_handle) %>
```

I am able to sort, but the method sort_update are never call.

I use Rails 3.0.7 and Ruby 1.9.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's very particular about the elements' ID's. It has to be in the format of `string_integer`.

Try changing to:

```
<tr class="champ" id="view_<%= champ.id %>">
```

And as mentioned, close the `tr`

Comment: Probably the right answer. Docs are here: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/ScriptaculousHelper.html#method-i-sortable_element

Answer (score 0):

You are not closing the `tr` tag. I'm also wondering how you can sort a list which includes only one item.